# Creating string array from a textbox full of randomly distributed different numbers

Tags: c#, string, textbox, decimal

In a visual c#project I am converting textbox into string and splitting that string into string array. But array can only hold integer values, when it comes to a decimal it stops and never goes on with other numbers in the textbox. How can I deal with that. The code is like this;

```
string phrase = textBox8.ToString();

            string[] words = new string[100];

            words = phrase.Split((string[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any separator that could be used to split the input string into arrays before checking if a particular value in array is number or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your variable phrase should be:

```
string phrase = textBox8.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped me alot.

Comment: Why do a `.ToString()` on `textBox8.Text` when `.Text` is already a `string`?